# Unfilled parameter and static method in Python

Tags: python, windows, class, object

This is a program related to windows operations. I have made different versions of this program. So I tried writing a version using classes. I am a beginner and thought this will help me understand the concept but I am getting some errors like

```
Method 'shutdown_windows' may be 'static'
```

There are many errors like this and I would like to get some insight about them and how to solve them

This is my code:

```
import os
import datetime
import time


class WindowsOperations(object):
    def __init__(self, shutdown, restart, open_app, close_app):
        self.shutdown = shutdown
        self.restart = restart
        self.open_app = open_app
        self.close_app = close_app

    def shutdown_windows(self):
        time.sleep(remaining_time)
        while True:
            if time_hour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and time_minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute:  #
                os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
                break

    def restart_windows(self):
        time.sleep(remaining_time)
        while True:
            if time_hour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and time_minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute:
                os.system("shutdown /r /t 1")
                break

    def open_application(self):
        app_name_open = input("Enter the application name you want to open: ").lower() + ".exe"
        time.sleep(remaining_time)
        while True:
            if time_hour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and time_minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute:
                os.startfile(app_name_open)
                break

    def close_application(self):
        app_name_close = input("Enter the application name you want to close: ").lower() + ".exe"
        time.sleep(remaining_time)
        while True:
            if time_hour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and time_minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute:
                os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM " + app_name_close)
                break


choice = int(input("Enter your choice \n1.Shutdown Windows \n2.Restart Windows "
                   "\n3.Open an application \n4.Close an application \n:"))
time_hour = int(input("Enter hour: "))
time_minutes = int(input("Enter minutes: "))
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
remaining_time = ((time_minutes - time_now.minute) * 60 + (time_hour - time_now.hour) * 3600) % 86400
print(remaining_time)
my_windows_operation = WindowsOperations('shutdown', 'restart', 'open_app', 'close_app')
if choice == 1:
    my_windows_operation.shutdown_windows()
elif choice == 2:
    my_windows_operation.restart_windows()
elif choice == 3:
    my_windows_operation.open_application()
elif choice == 4:
    my_windows_operation.close_application()
else:
    print("Please enter a valid input")
```

Please do modify the code if necessary and give me some tips

Comment: What is it you don't understand? You've defined your constructor to take several arguments, but you don't pass your constructor any. If I do something like `def foo(a, b):...` what do you expect to happen when I do `foo()`? It's the same idea. If you don't plan on using any arguments, don't define your functions that way

Comment: Yes, I have changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

The second "Parameter 'shutdown' unfilled" is an error. It's coming because you've defined `WindowsOperations` intitializer to take 4 parameters:

```
def __init__(self, shutdown, restart, open_app, close_app):
```

But when actually creating the object you are passing noothing:

```
my_windows_operation = WindowsOperations()
```

You definitely need to fix that.

The first "Method 'shutdown_windows' may be 'static'" is more of a suggestion. It's coming because the method `shutdown_windows` does not use `self` - i.e. it need not be part of the class to do it's job.

Comment: So what can I do to prevent this? Should  I not use Classes at all and just define them using functions?

Comment: For the "static" suggestion, yuou can ignore it if you want. The code will still work. That's just your linter being pedantic.

Comment: So if I write it like this, will the code function properly?

my_windows_operation = WindowsOperations('shutdown', 'restart', 'open_app', 'close_app')

Comment: @RavuriPraneeth pass the required arguments? Change the signature to not require arguments? What is the purpose of all those attributes anyway, you don't seem to use them at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you suggest? I am a beginner and I am just starting to learn classes. So it would be nice to give me some clear answers.

Comment: @RavuriPraneeth I can't design your class for you. You have to make these decisions. I gave you two clear options for how to *avoid the error*